How might a civilization that comes after us be aided by the fact someone has been here and done it before?
Suppose a hypothetical apocalypse scenario that wipes out all human beings, but leaves infrastructure and the like behind. In particular, digital technologies are mostly unaffected. Consider then, that an amount of time passes, allowing nature to reclaim the earth, and a fair bit of natural interdiction of our civilization to take place.
Now, say another intelligent species arose, also bipedal, perhaps even descended from apes like us, but benefitting from a 'buff' in cognitive capability. They are by all relevant metrics, smarter and more capable than us.
All other things being equal, how big an aid is the fact our ruined - but still somewhat intact civilization is now their stomping ground? How much of a guidebook towards building civilization could be put together from studying the ruins of our own? Would they progress faster than us? Slower? In different or similar directions? How soon until milestones such as the wheel, forging iron tools, the steam engine, the combustion engine, powered flight, splitting the atom, space travel?

Whilst interesting, this question seems a little underconstrained... I'm not sure it passes the "would a good answer involve writing an entire book?" test. Consider concentrating on a specific bit of technology (say, steam power) and detailing the setting a bit (like, how long ago were humans wiped out? last wednesday? 100 years ago? 35000 years ago? 140 million years ago?). What do you want from "digital technologies are unaffected"? Were you aware that electrolytic capacitors have a potentially quite limited lifetime, for example?

It would take magic to prevent digital technologies from deteriorating. Just sitting on a shelf, digital technology deteriorates. Atoms in the transistors migrate which destroy the semiconductors. Resistors fade. Even today, the advanced digital technology is incomprehensible to many people and can be compared to magic. I doubt any being who does not have high technology already would be able to reverse engineer and understand our digital technology.


How soon until milestones such as the wheel, forging iron tools, the steam engine, the combustion engine, powered flight, splitting the atom, space travel?

They will be unable to reach most of these milestones. In particular, the earliest steam engines cannot be made without plentiful and readily accessible deposits of high grade coal, of which they consumed truly prodigious amounts: so much so that for several decades, it only made economic sense to build a steam engine right on top of a coal mine. (The economic case was that the steam engines pumped out water from the mines, allowing access to coal deposits below the local water table.) But it just so happens that we have already extracted the best coal deposits; while there remains a lot of coal in the ground, it is either difficult to access, or lower grade, or both. The coal deposits are not renewable on timescales which would also allow any meaningful traces of civilisation to be preserved.
If your goal is to industrialise, coal cannot be substituted with wood. You can make iron tools using wood for fuel, but for mass producing steel machinery, even all the forests of Earth will not suffice. Without plentiful machine-worked steel, you would not be able to have internal combustion engine; and because there would be no steam engines and also not enough coal and steel for a railway network, the economy will just not develop to require as much powered overland travel anyway. Lack of internal combustion engine means no powered flight, which in turn means no splitting the atom: remember, it was developed as a weapon, to be delivered to target by internal combustion engine-powered flying machines (i.e. warplanes), and without an electrical grid, there would be no economical case for civilian uses of nuclear energy either. (And there will be no economical case for electricity grid due to lack of mass-produced electrical devices, due to lack of machine-based manufacture, due to lack of coal, due to lack of steam engines to access the remaining deep/low-grade deposits, due to lack of shallow high-grade deposits which we have already extracted and which are not coming back anytime soon.)
But!
...if your apocalypse occurs in say the 18th century, none of the above constraints apply. I would not expect the new species to advance much faster  or to achieve things which humans will not. Its progress will still be subject to economic and physical limitations; you cannot argue with the law of supply and demand and win any more that you can with the law of gravity. But everything that exists in our world, they will be able to achieve too.

When you look at the rate of deforestation during the early Industrial Revolution, it's clear that there was more than enough wood to be sustainable, but that our ancestors made no attempt to replant the forests that they were cutting down.  A smarter (less greedy) species than our own could have maintained thier forests without ever switching to coal.

@Nosajimiki, thank you. And this deforestation, combined with a lack of replanting, suggests that sustainably sourced wood was too expensive as fuel even in the early stages of Industrial Revolution. In that case clear-cutting the forest, selling the standing crop of trees for whatever they can fetch, and turning the land over to some different use makes perfect economic sense, especially given how the first industrial regions always just so happened to sit on shallow coal deposits. But of course a smarter species could always avoid switching to coal by not industrialising.

Replanting a forest is way less labor intensive than cutting it down and turning it into charcoal.  The problem was not that they could not, it's that they did not.  But if they did, then the price of wood would have remained cheap.   Because it is underground, it's actually more labor intensive to dig up coal and process it into coke than it is to cut down trees for charcoal... but only if you have enough land set aside for trees to do it sustainably.  The problem is that humans don't like waiting 10+ years for thier investments to mature when that same land could yield 10 food harvests

@nosajimiki, thank you. No, wood could not compete with coal on price. Even with the additional upfront investment and labor required to run a mine, you could extract energy from the ground far quicker than from a sustainable forest. A wood burner might produce a few tons of charcoal per firing, which might take over a week to complete; a miner might produce several tons of coal per day. And this greater volume drove coal's unit costs down, so just as you would expect, historically coke was cheaper than charcoal.

You are correct in that by the late part of the industrial revolution, coke was way cheaper than charcoal, but you are missing a lot of context.  First off turning coal into coke required burning it in kiln just like charcoal, but it takes a lot longer 15-35hr as opposed to 7-8hr.   Your week thing is simply incorrect. It took rows of dozens or even hundreds of these kilns running at the same time to process all the needed coke just like you saw happen with charcoal kilns during the early IR.  Also, at the beginning of the IR, wood was simply way cheaper.

Coal had already been a known fuel source for 1000s of years, but it was more expensive in most parts of Europe because it has to be mined which is more labor intensive than felling; so, it was rarely used.  So, even though coal and coke were known about, they were just not worth the cost until after Europe became deforested. Deforestation meant that Europe had to start importing wood from its colonies which drove the price of wood way up which is when/how coal became cheaper.  The final detail is the beehive kiln.

After the switch to coke happened, more and more new technologies needing steel came out and the demand for higher volumes lead to a new style of industrial sized kiln that could process many tons of coal in a single firing. The same method can be used for charcoal, but never was because the demand for steel was not high enough to justify it until after the deforestation had already happened.

So, it was through mechanization and economy of scale that by the late industrial era, coke was cheaper than charcoal ever was, but if you take all of the technology of the late IR and bring it back to a time before deforestation had already taken its toll, then charcoal would still be the cheaper resource.

@Nosajimiki. thank you. No, the limit would not have been technological but biological: the Earth's forests just do not produce enough timber to sustain an industrial revolution. By importing wood, pre-industrial Europe was effectively mining other continents' old growth forests, which could be harvested without having to wait for them to regrow. And even that was unsustainable, given that Europe's deforestation was merely slowed rather than stopped, even though it already supplemented itself with coal. That's not a condition for a non-coal-based industrial revolution to take place.

Europe took over 100 years to cut down its forests with no attempts to replant them, but  with proper spacing and species selection, it only takes 10 years to fully replace the cut down biomass.  They could have multiplied thier steel production 10 fold and still kept it sustainable. Non-sustainable logging was a choice.

@Nosajimiki, thank you. No, you cannot replace an old growth forest in 10 years. It's called 'old growth' for a reason, and this reason is that it has been growing undisturbed for longer; much longer. 10 years is just the period of most rapid growth; at this age, a tree is still far from its mature size. You just cannot replicate with a 10-year rotation the bounty of logging a new patch of old growth forest each year; sorry. The best you can do is drive the price of timber low enough to make managed woodlands unprofitable...

...and that then would be the choice behind Europe's unsustainable logging: have less wood now because you refrain from mining colonial forests, or have less wood in the future when the colonial forests are exhausted and your own are turned to other, more profitable uses. But that's only really a choice when wood is plentiful, and pre-industrial Europe already had a shortage of wood; it needed all the wood it could get just to keep itself going.

Old growth forests have larger trees, but they are fewer and more diverse than farmed trees.  Pine farms are planted at densities up to 1700 trees per acre whereas an old growth forest will typically have ~30-150 actual trees due to natural die off as the trees compete for resources; so, you get a similar amount of total wood from the younger trees.  Also, charcoaling requires that larger logs be split and same species be charcoaled together; so, an old, diverse wood forest is less ideal anyway.  Old wood is only important for lumber, but charcoal and paper does best with renewables.

@Nosajimiki, thank you. I'm glad that you were the one to mention this. Using lumber for construction of buildings and other objects means setting some forests aside to grow construction-grade timber, which limits the output of fuel wood. That of course makes the case for a coal-free Industrial Revolution weaker still.

Not really, even with the longer 25-30 years it takes to farm lumber, the demand for lumber grade wood is very small compared to other uses of wood like paper and charcoal.  If in the 1700s, the world were to allocate just 4-5% of its forests to renewable lumber production, everyone in the world could own a 2000sqft wooden home today... actual demand when you consider most parts of the world builds smaller or uses other materials is probably closer to 1.5-2%.

@Nosajimiki, thank you. And even those 1-2% of world's forests would still represent a prohibitively large proportion of world's accessible forests. Wood is bulky, and before steam-powered trains, the only economical long distance transport option for bulky goods was over water. For this reason, only the forests located close to major rivers or a coast could contribute to world's wood supply, and these forests are in fact quite scarce, especially given that these same areas are also best locations for agriculture and settlements.

Currently, 7% of the world's forests are perfectly accessible, renewable, and commercially exploited plantation forests.  These forests currently cover the majority of the world's lumber and paper needs, and incinerating just thier byproducts (leaves and small branches) covers 9% of the global power budget.  If we were to reclaim all the lands that were clearcut for charcoal, and not replanted during the industrial revolution to grow new trees, those lands would produce over 100% of the world's current power, lumber, and paper needs.

@Nosajimiki, thank you. Also, this harvest critically depends on machines and logistic chains powered by fuels derived from oil. It would not be possible without them, and of course in a pre-industrial economy none of these things are available. Biomass alone simply does not provide enough energy to allow this amount of wood to be harvested and distributed and also to sustain an economy that produces enough demand for wood, without which demand harvesting such amounts of wood would be pointless in the first place.

Assuming this civilization has something similar in pattern recognition and language to humans they could likely learn plenty from any books that survive.  Books are relatively delicate in that they are made of thin sheets of flammable biodegradable materials but we've discovered some very old books, papers, and similar materials that are still readable.  This civilization would likely learn our languages much like we do, starting with illustrated books that have words that describe the items/nouns and actions/verbs being shown.  As they learn words they can translate materials of increasing complexity over time.
The books would show what some real world items should look like and work like even if the items are damaged, decayed, rusted, and have parts missing.  Damaged books would likewise have real world examples to build from to fill in blanks left from damaged pages or lost volumes of an album of books.  Many photographs and motion picture films should survive to show realistic depictions of what things do and how they work.
The creatures that make up this civilization might have to be somewhat comparable in size and shape to humans, and have similar sensory perception, to make much of what we leave behind.  If they view light/colors differently then ink on paper might be largely invisible to them, photographs might not match reality like we'd expect them to.  If they have hands, or whatever, that are excessively smaller or larger than our own then it would be difficult to manipulate and explore the tools and utensils we leave behind.
I don't know how well digital records would survive if left without being maintained and protected.  As it is now there's records lost because the machines built to store and replay them have been damaged and reverse engineering the systems has proven difficult without some frame of reference to work from.
Anything not "micro" or "nano" would likely be reverse engineered fairly quickly.  We can teach a child to read and then from there a decade or two later they can practically teach themselves to take complex machines apart and put them back together, in the process learning how they work, then make repairs, adjustments, improvements, or some such shortly after.  If the pieces are too small to see with the unaided eye, and manipulate with basic hand tools, then that's a specialty that could take far longer to master without guidance from someone already skilled in that field.
